# @counter giving no output - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null

I am trying to make a word counter in Rails, Text is a scaffold name,but my
@counter variable doesn't seem to be giving any output how can i fix this

```
class TextsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_text, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


 def index
  @texts = Text.all
 end


def new
 @text = Text.new
end

def edit
end

def create

 @text = Text.new(text_params)
 @counter = @text.name.split.size

end




private
 def set_text
   @text = Text.find(params[:id])
 end


def text_params
  params.require(:text).permit(:name, :string)
end
```

end

VIEW

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

```
<%= @text.name %>
```

```
<%= @counter %>
```

Comment: What is in `@text.name`?

Comment: the text which is supposed to be counted of course

Comment: What I mean is, when you get nothing in the counter.  What is it set to?

Comment: What do you mean what @text.name's value is? its 'xyz'

Comment: And what does `@counter` output?

Comment: it outputs Nothing that's the problem

Comment: What is the name of your view file?

Comment: This question is faar from an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code `create` method cannot show variable. You have to move in your `show` method. You can create new `show` method contains.

```
def show
 @counter = @text.name.split.size
end
```

change your method `create` into:

```
def create
  @text = Text.new(text_params)
  if @text.save
    redirect_to texts_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

and you can go to in show page. It will show `@counter`

Comment: `@text.name` would be set to the parameters passed which means `@counter = @text.name.split.size` would work.  I'm guessing he's simply not using a `create.html.erb` file

Comment: Yes, you're right it does not create `create.html.erb`. what page do you want to show the parameter?

Comment: Thanks Japed and Muhamad, i wanted the counter to show on the show.html.erb but instead I had the @counter assigned in the create function.

Comment: I'm sorry @japed. I thought, you're the person who asks the question. :)